ibus predictive text not working ubuntu 22.04
I'm new to ubuntu and really please with it a a replacement for windows.  I'm very strong in linux most RHEL/OEL, however not with gnome or KDE
I have not been able to get ibus predictive text to work ... nothing happen when I press <-super-><-space->.   However when i press <-super-><.> a "e" with a underline appears and then  the emoji menu appears ... clicking a emoji inserts it.
Been working on this for about 2 weeks
